# #git How can I commit my folder through git?

Tags: git

As I am new to git, I committed a folder without `message(-m)` so it opened a `vim` folder which is new to me. So I just cancelled the window, from that time I am unable to `add` or `commit` anything.

I even removed(deleted) the file I committed it doesn't work.
It is again showing the same error.

```
$ git add.

fatal: Unable to create 
'C:/Users/alubi/OneDrive/Desktop/Code/c tutorials/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure that you have closed any editors or other Git-related tools that might have been opened, such as the Vim editor that was triggered during the failed commit.
- Since the error message indicates that the file `index.lock` exists, you can manually delete it. Open the command line or terminal and navigate to your repository's root directory. Then, execute the following command(for linux):

```
rm -f .git/index.lock
```

For Windows cmd:

```
del .git\index.lock
```

- Execute the `git status` command to check if the lock file has been successfully removed and if Git is now in a clean state.`If the lock file has been removed, you should see a clean status without any error messages.`
- Once the lock file has been removed, you can attempt to add or commit your changes again using the respective Git commands, such as `git add .` and `git commit -m "Your commit message"`. Make sure to include a commit message this time to avoid triggering the Vim editor again.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to delete the lock file.

```
### On Linux-based machine:
$ rm -f .git/index.lock

### On Windows Command Prompt, try:
del .git\index.lock
```

> When you perform a Git command that edits the index, Git creates a new `index.lock` file writes the changes and then renames the file.
>
> The `index.lock` file indicates to other Git processes that the repository is locked for editing.

Comment: @Srinivas0010 Delete this lock file only after having checked and tried to exit all running git process (maybe because you have not exited from Vim). Check with a process listing tool of your operating system.